# 'Mostly' compatibility on Openprinting.org?

Tags: printing

When searching for laser printers from the desired manufacturer and targeted price range using [Openprinting.org](http://www.openprinting.org/printers) site, the best I can get for compatibility with Ubuntu is 'mostly' ([explained here](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/openprinting/database/databaseintro) and looks like this- [image: mostly][image: mostly]). I am uncertain what exactly 'mostly' means. Where or how can I search for laser printers that are perfectly compatible with Ubuntu? Any recommendations for any printers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About searching for perfectly working printers: the openprinting website lets you sort by manufacturer. [Here is a list for HP](http://www.openprinting.org/printers/manufacturer/HP). You will get the printers marked with [image][image][image] first and below that the printers marked [image][image]

I used HP as an example for a reason: I have yet to purchase a HP printer that did not work in Ubuntu. Currently I have a [HP PSC 2175](http://www.openprinting.org/printer/HP/HP-PSC_2175) all-in-one and printer, scanner and card reader work out of the box.

And to finish it off: 'mostly' seems to be adressing printers that do work but have some minor issues (mostly not about printing). But to support Linux and you having the best experience... pick one from the once that do work flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Konica Minolta PagePro 1400W black and white laser. Konica Minolta tell you there is not any Linux support for it, and they don't have any. It is not listed in the openprinting.org site on their printer list, however, if you do some searching, there is a PPD on their site for this printer. It is rated with 2 Penguins. It works perfectly fine with Ubuntu.